# Remove kibana text from the iframe loading screen

Tags: iframe, logstash, kibana

I want to remove the "kibana" loading text from the iframe of kibana dashboards. Any pointers on which file i can change for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In the previous versions, kibana 4.1 and earlier you can change the text in index.html placed in /opt/kibana/src/public/.

Answer (score 0):

With 4.3, you can edit kibana/src/ui/views/uiApp.jade at line 28.